# Using Firebug debugger to solve script conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, dojo, javascript-debugger

My page was working perfectly and suddenly, the hero image is not loading and I am seeing an error message in the console "ReferenceError: imagesLoaded is not defined" on wine-cheese.js, which is preceeded by another error "Error: multipleDefine" on dojo.js. I have not changed the files since the content launched 6 weeks ago.

Some external developers have been doing some work on the site and I believe they have introduced a conflict. But I am stumped as to how to figure it out.  I tried setting breakpoints in Firebug but that isn't helping me because I'm not really sure what I'm doing.  All of the tutorials I find about how to use the debugger focus on one script within a page rather than debugging a page that is part of a CMS and merged with many other scripts you have no control over.

When I check the content locally, everything works OK (I used absolute links to reference all the scripts and files to be sure they are actually on the server), so I think there is a conflict with dojo, or maybe even something else.

I have been trying to figure this out all day and feel like I am going in circles.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated. The page in question is [here](http://www.lecreuset.com/content_wine-and-cheese).

Here is the code in the javascript file that causes the error.  The site I work on has jQuery 1.3.2 so we have to use noConflict to run a newer library in parallel (hence the jwc)

```
    $.fn.tabs = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $el = $(this);
            var $panels = $el.find('> div');
            var $tabs = $el.find('> ul a');
            $tabs.click(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if (window.location.hash) {
                        window.scrollTo(0, 489);
                    }
                }, 1);

                $tabs.removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                $panels.fadeOut(250);
                $panels.filter(this.hash).animate({
                    opacity:1},
                250, 'linear', function(){
                    $(this).show();
                });

                animateHeader(this.hash);
                //window.location.hash = this.hash;
                //return false;
            });
            if(window.location.hash != 'undefined' && window.location.hash != '') {
                //alert(window.location.hash);
                tabId = '[href*="' + window.location.hash + '"]';
                $tabs.filter(tabId).click();
            } else {
                $tabs.filter('[href*="#party-tips"]').click();
            }
        });
    };

    jQuery.easing.def = "easeInCubic";

    function animateHeader(tab) {
        if (tab == "#party-tips") {
            $('#party-tips #iconcircle').animate({
                left:0
            },750, 'easeInCubic');
            $('#party-tips #mask').animate({
                left:980,
                width:0,
            }, 1200, 'easeInCubic');
        } else if(tab == "#pairing-guide") {
            $('#pairing-guide #iconcircle').animate({
                left:0
            },750, 'easeInCubic');
            $('#pairing-guide #mask').animate({
                left:980,
                width:0,
            }, 1200, 'easeInCubic');
        } else if(tab == "#quick-tips") {
            $('#quick-tips #iconcircle').animate({
                left:0
            },750, 'easeInCubic');
            $('#quick-tips #mask').animate({
                left:980,
                width:0,
            }, 1200, 'easeInCubic');
        }
    }

    function laodAnimation() {
        imagesLoaded('img#sipbg', function(){
            $('#loadblock').hide();
            $('img#sipbg').animate({
                opacity:1
            }, 250, 'linear');
            $('#top-block').delay(250).animate({
                top:0
            }, 350, 'swing', function(){
                $('h1#wc-logo').animate({
                    top:30,
                    left:84
                }, 750, 'linear', function(){
                    $('span#wine-glass').animate({
                        top:105,
                        left:136
                    }, 500, 'swing', function(){
                        $('span#text-sip').fadeIn(250, function(){
                            $('span#text-savor').delay(500).fadeIn(250, function(){
                                $('span#text-repeat').delay(500).fadeIn(350, function() {
                                    $(this).delay(500).fadeOut(350, function(){ 
                                        $(this).delay(500).fadeIn(350, function() {
                                            $(this).delay(500).fadeOut(350, function(){ 
                                                $(this).delay(500).fadeIn(350, function() {
                                                    $('span##text-endless').delay(500).fadeIn(350);
                                                    $('#bottom-block').animate({
                                                        bottom:0
                                                    }, 350, 'swing', function() {
                                                        $('#bottom-block h1').delay(350).fadeIn(750);
                                                    });
                                                });
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });

            $('#main-grid').delay(400).animate({
                opacity:1
            }, 1200, 'linear');
        });
    }
```

The first part of the content I plug into the CMS looks like this; imagesLoaded is defined in the second script:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.lecreuset.com/wcsstore/CVWEB/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="http://www.lecreuset.com/wcsstore/CVWEB/js/jquery.fancybox.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="http://www.lecreuset.com/wcsstore/CVWEB/js/retina.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="http://www.lecreuset.com/wcsstore/CVWEB/js/wine-cheese.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-53d6affc389982ed"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var jwc = jQuery.noConflict(true);
            jwc(document).ready(function() {
                jwc("a#box").fancybox({
                        maxWidth    : 800,
                        maxHeight   : 680,
                        fitToView   : true,
                        width       : '70%',
                        height      : '90%',
                        autoSize    : true,
                        closeClick  : false,
                        openEffect  : 'none',
                        closeEffect : 'none'
                    });
                laodAnimation();    
            }); 
        </script>
```

Comment: you have about 50 scripts included, some of them twice, allmost all jquery versions... this is a little bit crazy 8-/

Comment: @reyaner you're telling me! its a pain to work with. unfortunately i have little control over the scripts and how they are included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using either chrome/chromium or safari for their web console.  You can then open up the web inspector and set the inspector to catch all errors. [image: Graphical Representation]

The tools there should help you figure out where the problem is.

### Update:

Looking at the link you provided I saw the problem is with the imageloader.js call.  It seems to be defining multiple times the same object. You could try wrapping it in a js check.

### Update 2:

Ok so I tested your scripts in jsfiddle. I found the problem to be based in a conflict between dojo and the imagesloaded script. I set up a jsfiddle to test out the scripts to see if the class imagesLoader is defined.  In the left toolbar if you change in the settings on the left between jQuery and Dojo frameworks the imagesLoaded js script stops working. The problem is that since it is packaged it doesn't signal an error.  Either you make a new script from scratch or find an alternative.

```
if(!alreadyDefined) {
   alreadyDefined=true;
   //Rest of your code.
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your steps in Chrome, but none of the exceptions I see in the stack are in either of the files mentioned in the console, or in imagesloaded.js.  I'm glad to know about this anyway.   Would I wrap the imagesLoaded function in wine-cheese.js with the code above, or would I wrap all the code in imagesloaded.min.js in that?